# How to Update MYSQL Table Column Based on Value in Related Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a Table A as follows:

```
ID NAME VALUE
1  abc  10
2  xyz  15
```

I have a TABLE B as follows:

```
ID VALUE_1 VALUE_2 VALUE_3 TOTAL YEAR
1  0       0       0       0     2012
2  0       0       0       0     2013
3  0       0       0       0     2012
```

I want to `UPDATE` all rows in `Table B` and `SET` `VALUE_2` column to the `VALUE` in `Table A`

I started my query statement as follows:

```
$query_string = '
UPDATE Table_B
SET VALUE_2 = (SELECT...something should go here I think)
WHERE Table_B.year = "2013"
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: what's the link / join column between tables? or you just want the aggregate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE  tableB b
        INNER JOIN tableA a
            ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.YEar = 2013
SET     b.VALUE_2 = a.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/304c3/1)

Comment: @H.Ferrence see my updated answer. I added `AND b.YEar = 2013` to select only records on 2013.

Comment: No problem @JW...pointing me in the direction of using INNER JOIN helped me to structure my query, which I did and tested and it  worked. Thanks !